# Appsettings.json - Deserialize the entire appsettings into a single object - NOT just a section

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a complex appsettings.json - something like this.

```
{
  "authentication": {
    "azureAd": {
      "aadInstance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
      "domain": "[TENANT_NAME].onmicrosoft.com",
      "tenantId": "[TENANT_ID]",
      "clientId": "[CLIENT_ID]",
      "clientSecret": "[CLIENT_SECRET]",
      "callbackPath": "[CALLBACK_URL]"
    }
  },

  "connectionStrings": [
    {
      "name": "MyDbContext",
      "connectionString": "[CONNECTION_STRING]"
    }
  ],

  "logging": {
    "includeScopes": false,
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Debug",
      "system": "Information",
      "microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to deserialize the file into an Object. I've created a corresponding POCO.
I don't want to retrieve individual sections , would rather have them in 'one' place. I don't want to do this, for example, to get the auth settings,  ( `var auth = this.Configuration.Get<AuthenticationSettings>("authentication")`

I want to access my 'entire' appsettings object, So I can get all settings from appsetting class.

Do this? then what?  Is there a better solution?

```
 var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
```

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all object in `appSettings.json` like the following. `configuration` is `IConfiguration`

```
var config = configuration.Get<ConfigurationModel>();
```

e.g model:

```
public class ConfigurationModel
{
    public string AllowedHosts { get; set; } = "";
    public ConnectionString? ConnectionStrings { get; set; }
    public AzureSettings? AzureSettings { get; set; }
}
```